# Add autoplay on CSS slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I would like to add an autoplay functionality to my css slider but not sure if it is possible with the current code structure.

on comment i give my working link of codepan

Thanks
here is css code

Comment: https://codepen.io/km_likhon/pen/GELoap

Comment: You should put the link/code in your question.

Comment: https://codepen.io/km_likhon/pen/GELoap


here is problem i can not add link 

see this link thanks

@JeroenHeier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an interval, you can simulate clicks on your radios...

```js
var delay = 1500;
var sliderRadios = document.getElementsByName("carousel-3d");
var index=0
var imageCount = sliderRadios.length;

setInterval(function(){
  index++;
  if(index>imageCount-1){
    index=0;
  }
  sliderRadios[index].click();
  console.log(sliderRadios[index].id);
},delay);
```

```css
.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 350px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.carousel-3d-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

#carousel-3d-controller-2 ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(1),
#carousel-3d-controller-1 ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(1),
#carousel-3d-controller-2 ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(2),
#carousel-3d-controller-1 ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(2),
#carousel-3d-controller-2 ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(3),
#carousel-3d-controller-1 ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(3),
{
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.48, .16, .15, .98);
}

.carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(2),
#carousel-3d-controller-1:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(2),
#carousel-3d-controller-2:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(3),
#carousel-3d-controller-3:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateX(-175px) translateZ(-130px);
  opacity: .9;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.48, .16, .15, .98);
}

.carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(1),
#carousel-3d-controller-1:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(1),
#carousel-3d-controller-2:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(2),
#carousel-3d-controller-3:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.48, .16, .15, .98);
}

.carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(3),
#carousel-3d-controller-1:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(3),
#carousel-3d-controller-2:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(1),
#carousel-3d-controller-3:checked ~ .carousel-3d-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateX(175px) translateZ(-130px);
  opacity: .9;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.48, .16, .15, .98);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <figure id="carousel--3d">
    <input type="radio" name="carousel-3d" id="carousel-3d-controller-1" />
    <input type="radio" name="carousel-3d" id="carousel-3d-controller-2" />
    <input type="radio" name="carousel-3d" id="carousel-3d-controller-3" />
    <label for="carousel-3d-controller-1" class="carousel-3d-item">
      <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/250?image=974" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-content">
        <img src="assets/dist/img/easy.png">
        <p>Win Discounts cccc</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label for="carousel-3d-controller-2" class="carousel-3d-item">
      <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/250?image=974" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-content">
        <img src="assets/dist/img/easy.png">
        <p>Win Discounts bbbb</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label for="carousel-3d-controller-3" class="carousel-3d-item">
      <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/250?image=974" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide-content">
        <img src="assets/dist/img/easy.png">
        <p>Win Discounts aaaa</p>
      </div>
    </label>
  </figure>
</div>
```

***You better look at the snippet in full page (link at upper-right corner).***

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to do this with just CSS, but it is pretty easy to do with JavaScript.

```
let selected = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input');
setInterval(() => {
  buttons[(selected++) % buttons.length].click();
}, 1000);
```

This works for your simple example, but you may want a more specific selector for larger applications see [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).